# Resume Question regarding graduate school

Tags: resume, education

I am about to graduate from college (undergrad) in the upcoming months and have been accepted into graduate school for computational mathematics. Truth is, grad school is my second choice and would rather find a decent job and get some *real world* work experience. Since some of the jobs I would be applying for are related to my graduate program, would it be worth mentioning on my resume as some sort of achievement? I can definitely see why I wouldn't want to mention it, but I feel like sort of attests to my ability to be successful and sort of acts like I've been filtered out among 100's of other applicants who did not get in.

I am new to this so I just want to come off as a strong candidate for any job relevant to my college major. Thanks for any input I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear who you you are targeting your resume to - the grad school admissions' office or some prospective employer.If it is a prospective employer, that prospective employer is unlikely to be impressed with knowledge that you have yet to acquire. You are going to compete against a bunch of individuals who have knowledge they can demonstrate they have. That makes you toast.

Comment: NOt only that, saying you have been accepted ina graduate problem coudl mark you down as likley to leave soon whcih is nota good thing when interviewiing. I see no up side to telling htem.